# Swagger sending empty post requests

Tags: php, laravel, api, swagger

I just set up swagger for laravel 5.1 (old project)
I wrote entire documentation for my project but the problem is that when I go
Try it out!
It sends empty requests.
And when I try the exact same thing with postman it works like its supposed to.

This is an example:

```
 /**
 * @SWG\Post(
 *     path="/api-routes/verify-report",
 *     consumes={"multipart/form-data"},
 *     description="Verify report",
 *     operationId="verifyReport",
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         description="Application report id",
 *         format="int64",
 *         in="path",
 *         name="report_id",
 *         required=true,
 *         type="string"
 *     ),           
 *     produces={"application/json"},
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response="200",
 *         description="successful operation"
 *     ),
 *     summary="Verify report",
 *     tags={
 *         "Verify report"
 *     }
 * )
 * */
public function verifyReport() {

}
```

And I'm using

```
"darkaonline/l5-swagger": "~3.0"
```

Comment: "Empty requests" meaning requests without a body? If so, it's likely because your code annotations do not define any parameters (in this case -
 `in="formData"` parameters) for the request. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You just need to change few changes like this bellow.**

```
/**
 * @SWG\Post(
 *     path="/api-routes/verify-report",
 *     consumes={"multipart/form-data"},
 *     description="Verify report",
 *     operationId="verifyReport",
 *     consumes={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
 *     produces={"application/json"},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         description="Application report id",
 *         in="forData",
 *         name="report_id",
 *         required=false,
 *         type="string"
 *     ), 
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response="200",
 *         description="successful operation"
 *     ),
 *     summary="Verify report",
 *     tags={
 *         "Verify report"
 *     }
 * )
 * */
public function verifyReport() {

}
```